# What is the best way to install Laravel on HTML website that already use GIT?

Tags: php, html, git, laravel, github

I have a complete HTML website with all its folders CSS, JS & Images and already use Version Control by GIT.

What is the best way to install Laravel 5 on this website to keep GIT track the diversion from HTML to Laravel Framework smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to convert your current HTML website to laravel is very easy unless if you have some js backend:

1. Install Laravel
2. Move your CSS,JS,Images to laravel public folder
3. Move your html files to resource/views and rename them to name.blade.php or just name.php.
4. Fix the reference links of your css, js and images.
5. THE BIG PART!!! all your navigation will go through routes and backend logic in controllers.
   e.g. you wanna go to your about page! you will have a rule in your route which will redirect to a function in a controller and that function will call the view (html page currently) and optionally pass any information to the view.

These are very simple ways to transfer your website, but once you get into it you can learn many features of laravel that can optimize your site.